# Android In-App Billing Service aidl

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, in-app-billing, aidl

I'm trying to implement In-App Billing Service to sell in-app products. The first requirement is to import IInAppBillingService.aidl into the project but when I do, I get the following error. Even when I delete this file, plus all the autogenerated classes, I still get the same error

Program type already present: com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

Comment: check your package name and directory in which InappBillingService is present.Inside aidl directory, com.android.vending.billing package

Comment: Already tried. The package is present only once when added or 0 times when removed.

Comment: Are you sure you don't depend on a 3rd-party library to do something else, which might already contain in-app billing service. Possibly an Ads SDK or similar?

Comment: Found! There was a reference to a third party library somewhere where I couldn't see it. Thanks!